# how to remove the page numbering from the first slide

Tags: beamer, page-numbering

using `beamer`. Need remove page number at bottom-right of first slide.
Code Example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\title{Example}
\author{Bill Gates} 
\institute{University}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]

\begin{frame} 
    \titlepage
\end{frame}


\begin{frame} 
    \frametitle{Some string}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item Bill
        \item Knuth
        \item Straustrup
    \end{itemize}  
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can just move `\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]` to after the `\titlepage` `frame`...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have (at least) two options:

- Insert the instruction `\thispagestyle{empty}` immediately after the `\titlepage` instruction.
- As @Werner has already noted, you could move the instruction `\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]` to *after* the title frame.

Comment: No luatex based solution? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - not today... :-)