# How to insert a horizontal bar as a footnote at the end of a beamer slide in metropolis/mtheme?

Tags: beamer, citing, footnotes, beamer-metropolis

In a beamer slide, using mtheme/[metropolis](https://github.com/matze/mtheme) theme, it is difficult to create a small horizontal bar at the bottom of the slide showing author name or inserting some different text for every slide.

An answer exists [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26476/52071). But the page numbering starts from the title page. How to make the numbering start from the slide after the title page?
 And the ability to create a bar or some box around the footnotes would be excellent. Such bars exist by default in many different themes like the Madrid theme for beamer.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! A minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem would be excellent too. --- Ref Problem 1: [how to remove the page numbering from the first slide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/275247/124842), Problem 2: something like this [How to insert page number in Beamer Navigation Bars?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/137022/124842)

Comment: okay, the page numbering without the title page should be solvable by the first link, thanks!

Comment: @samcarter I am not sure I understood the difference between footnote and footline in the edit you made to the question. Thanks for your prompt answer. Let me try that. :)

Comment: @MycrofD Footline is what the box at the bottom of frames is called in beamer, the one containing things like author name, title and framenumber. A footnote is used to add information to something, for example `Shelock\footnote{the one with the silly hat and pipe} solved this case`

Comment: @samcarter well, then I meant footnote I believe. Because my intention is to insert a citation link at the bar in bottom instead of title or author names.

Comment: @MycrofD but do you want it to be displayed (possibly empty) on all slides or only the ones with citation?

Comment: @MycrofD Do you also want the three different colours from madrid?

Comment: @samcarter yeah, displayed empty. Yes, three different colours. And the option- if I don't want them displayed at all when there is no citation- should be helpful too.

Comment: Will there be slides with more then one citation?

Comment: yes yes. there will be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/388811/36296

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\author{names}
\title{text}


\makeatletter
\def\beamer@autobreakframebox{%
  \global\setbox\beamer@splitbox=\box\voidb@x%
  \ifbeamer@autobreak%
    % Ok, frame was overful -> split it!
    \setbox\@tempboxa=\vsplit\beamer@framebox to\beamer@autobreakfactor\textheight%
    \global\setbox\beamer@splitbox=\box\beamer@framebox%
    \@tempdima=\ht\beamer@splitbox%
    \ifdim\@tempdima<\beamer@autobreaklastheight%
      \global\beamer@autobreaklastheight=\@tempdima\relax%
    \else%
      \setbox\@tempboxa=\vbox{\unvbox\@tempboxa\unvbox\beamer@splitbox}%
      \global\setbox\beamer@splitbox=\box\voidb@x%
    \fi%
    \setbox\beamer@framebox=\vbox to\textheight{\unvbox\@tempboxa%
      \vskip\beamer@framebottomskipautobreak%
      \ifvoid\beamer@splitbox%
              \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,left]{footnote}
                    \usebeamerfont{footnote}%   
                    \ifvoid\beamer@footins%
                        \vskip\baselineskip%
                    \else%
                        \unvbox \beamer@footins%
                        \global\setbox\beamer@footins=\box\voidb@x%
                    \fi%
                    
                    \vskip-1.4\baselineskip%
                    \hspace{.5\paperwidth}%
                \parbox{.48\paperwidth}{%
                    \usebeamerfont{footnote}\strut\insertshortauthor\hfill\insertframenumber\quad%
                }%
              \end{beamercolorbox}%
      \fi%
      \beamer@exitcode%
    }%
  \else%
    \setbox\beamer@framebox=\vbox to\textheight{\unvbox\beamer@framebox%
      \vskip\beamer@framebottomskip%
              \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,left]{footnote}
                    \usebeamerfont{footnote}%   
                    \ifvoid\beamer@footins%
                        \vskip\baselineskip%
                    \else%
                        \unvbox \beamer@footins%
                        \global\setbox\beamer@footins=\box\voidb@x%
                    \fi%
                    
                    \vskip-1.4\baselineskip%
                    \hspace{.5\paperwidth}%
                \parbox{.48\paperwidth}{%
                    \usebeamerfont{footnote}\strut\insertshortauthor\hfill\insertframenumber\quad%
                }%
              \end{beamercolorbox}%
      \beamer@exitcode}%
    \global\setbox\beamer@footins=\box\voidb@x%
  \fi%
  }
\makeatother

\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\scriptsize}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\setbeamercolor{footnote}{fg=white,bg=mDarkTeal}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering]
    \titlepage
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
   test
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
   test\footcite{bertram}
   
   text\footcite{angenendt}
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
    text\footcite{angenendt}
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks good. But, if I want to insert a citation on a slide at the footnote(or footline) as a footcite [I am not sure if I am using the terms correctly] instead of 'names' and 'text', then what do I have to do?

Comment: @MycrofD Then it gets ugly .... let me dig for a similar question we had recently.

Comment: something like this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290740/52071, but with those 'foot-bars' from Madrid theme.

Comment: @MycrofD Is this going in the right direction?

Comment: yes @samcarter , absolutely. this is going in the right direction. Just a bar on the left showing the author's name, and page number on the right would make it complete.

Comment: I must say, you have done a great job.

Comment: @MycrofD The best I can offer is the references on the left hand site and the author in the centre.